# Chaining factors for lookup - is this the most efficient way?

Tags: r, processing-efficiency

I have two factors which I'm using as lookup-tables:

```
iState <- list("A" = "Alaska", "T" = "Texas", "G" = "Georgia")    
sCap <- list("Alaska" = "Juneau", "Texas" = "Austin", "Georgia" = "Atlanta")
```

And a vector to lookup:

```
foo <- c("T", "G", "A", "B", NA)
```

This code chains them together and gives me the lookup I want:

```
sCap[iState[foo] %>% as.character() %>%  na_if("NULL") ] %>% as.character() %>%  na_if("NULL")
# [1] "Austin"  "Atlanta" "Juneau"  NA        NA
```

Is this the most execution-time-efficient way to chain these factors together?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a lot better if you use lookup vectors instead of lookup lists. Basically, I changed `list` to `c()`, and then cut out all the `as.character` bits.

```
vState <- c("A" = "Alaska", "T" = "Texas", "G" = "Georgia")    
vCap <- c("Alaska" = "Juneau", "Texas" = "Austin", "Georgia" = "Atlanta")

vCap[vState[foo]]
```

---

Benchmarking methods so far:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  recode = foo %>%
    dplyr::recode(!!!iState, .default = NA_character_) %>%
    dplyr::recode(!!!sCap, .default = NA_character_),
  lists = sCap[iState[foo] %>% as.character() %>%  na_if("NULL") ] %>% as.character() %>%  na_if("NULL"),
  lists_no_pipe = na_if(as.character(sCap[na_if(as.character(iState[foo]), "NULL")]), "NULL"),
  vectors = unname(vCap[vState[foo]])
)
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval
#         recode 227.1 244.05 305.203 268.05 319.55 591.1   100
#          lists 182.2 198.85 244.964 222.10 254.20 562.6   100
#  lists_no_pipe  11.4  13.25  17.726  15.45  18.70  64.5   100
#        vectors   2.5   3.85   5.269   4.90   6.40  12.9   100
```

If you want things to be as fast as possible, don't use `%>%` - it's extra overhead. If you are doing complicated things, the extra microseconds from piping don't really matter. But in this case, the operations being done are already so quick that the few microseconds of piping actually account for a significant percentage of the execution time.

You may be able to go even faster--especially if your look-up tables are large, by using a join to a keyed `data.table` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use your `vCap[vState[foo]]` solution, and I'll look into keyed `data.table` too.

Comment: `data.table` won't be worth it if your data is, say, 100s of values or fewer. If you're looking at thousands or more of potential look-up values then `data.table` will probably be faster.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not very fast, especially because of the use of the functions `%>%` and `na_if()`.

I'm not sure if this is the fastest way, but if you just make `sCap` and `iState` into atomic vectors instead of lists (using `c()` instead of `list()`), you can get what you want very easily:

```
iState <- c(A = "Alaska", T = "Texas", G = "Georgia")    
sCap <- c(Alaska = "Juneau", Texas = "Austin", Georgia = "Atlanta")
foo <- c("T", "G", "A", "B", NA)

sCap[iState[foo]]
#    Texas   Georgia    Alaska      <NA>      <NA> 
# "Austin" "Atlanta"  "Juneau"        NA        NA
```

If it's important to you that the result is not named, you can use `unname()`:

```
unname(sCap[iState[foo]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Some might find this silly, but I love `dplyr::recode`:

```
foo %>%
  dplyr::recode(!!!iState, .default = NA_character_) %>%
  dplyr::recode(!!!sCap, .default = NA_character_)
[1] "Austin"  "Atlanta" "Juneau"  NA        NA
```

It works on lists or vectors.

Comment: Thanks - `recode` wasn't on my radar at all.  I'll play with that.